# Error while sending message (whatsapp-web.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to send a message by using whatsapp web.js I dont know why I am facing the error.

```
app.post("/send",(req,res)=>{
    const numbersBox = req.body.mobiles;
    const numbers = numbersBox.split(",")
    // loop through all the numbers and send message to each number.
    numbers.forEach(async eachNumber=>{
        const sanitized_number = eachNumber.toString().replace(/[- )(]/g, ""); // remove unnecessary chars from the number
        const final_number = `91${sanitized_number.substring(sanitized_number.length - 10)}`; // add 91(india code) before the number
        const number_details = await client.getNumberId(final_number); // get mobile number details
        if (number_details) {
            const sendMessageData = await client.sendMessage(final_number, req.body.message); // send message
        } else {
            console.log(final_number, "Mobile number is not registered");
        }
    })
})
```

When I tried to send messages without using forEach loop and sending message to single user it got succeeded but now it is showing below error

```
throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + helper_js_1.helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
                  ^

Error: Evaluation failed: Error: wid error: invalid wid
    at new c (https://web.whatsapp.com/app.c5b22a78d334f432a3c8.js:68:44944)
    at Object.s [as createWid] (https://web.whatsapp.com/app.c5b22a78d334f432a3c8.js:68:50062)
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:53
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\Users\prudh\OneDrive\Documents\projects\whatsapp\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\Users\prudh\OneDrive\Documents\projects\whatsapp\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
    at async Client.sendMessage (C:\Users\prudh\OneDrive\Documents\projects\whatsapp\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\src\Client.js:686:28)
    at async C:\Users\prudh\OneDrive\Documents\projects\whatsapp\index.js:57:37
```

Comment: One of the numbers in your loop might be improperly formatted. Can you place your `if / else` part of the code inside of a `try / catch`, and then in the `catch` part, `console.log(final_number)`?

Comment: I tried by the number is a valid number.

Comment: Do you have more than one number, when using the `.forEach`? If not, can you check if `numbers[0]` is a valid number, by using the `try / catch`? Also, when you `console.log(numbers)` before your `.forEach(...)`, what do you get?

Comment: the numbers are valid numbers, and i also tried by try,catch block and yes the numbers are valid on console.

Comment: I'm all out of ideas, then. Check [this](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/1441#issuecomment-1178965390), and see if any of the listed reasons apply to any of the numbers in your case. You could try and manually check if the individual numbers are on Whatsapp, or to try and find the offending number in your for loop with at `try / catch`, as I have suggested earlier.

Answer (score 0):

are you adding the "@c.us" at the end of the numbers? Every contact id should be like "5958978454@c.us" to consider it a valid number

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you didn't pass `chatId` properly in `client.sendMessage()`.

when using `client.sendMessage()` function, always pass `chatid`.

Example :

```
client.sendMessage(chatId,'Your Message');
```

Now understand what is chatId :

`chatId` look like this : `919988774455@c.us`

You can get `chatId` like this:

```
client.on('message', async (message) => {
    let chatId = message.from;
}
```

And then send a message using `client.sendMessage()` :

```
client.sendMessage(chatId,'Your Message');
```

You can also directly reply to a particular message, using `message.reply()`

Example :

```
client.on('message', async (message) => {
     message.reply('Your Message');
}
```

When using `message.reply()` function , you don't need to pass `chatId`.